# Why is the reset button for my game not working?

Tags: java

I have made a reset button which doesn't take away the focus of the KeyListener so that the game could still be playable after the clicking of the button. The rest of the button is all about resetting locations, emptying arraylists and arrays and so on. But it seems like whenever I click the restart button, the player object does go to its starting point, x = 2 y = 0. But after that whenever I make a move I see the man object/picture move to the position in was in before so the restart button isn't working at all. The player object is actually still at the location in which it stood when the restart button was clicked. I have read that there might be a second panel added beneath and thus the real panel not changing? I'm not sure and require your help.

My question specific: Why does the reset button not suffice for the changing of the player/man objects location, why is it failing?

```
package riddle;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel p2;
    private JButton reset;
    private GameDraw component;
    private Man m;


    public GameFrame() {
        this.setTitle("Riddle Man");
        this.setSize(719, 850);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        component = new GameDraw();
        m = new Man(component);
        component.addKeyListener(m);
        component.requestFocus();
        createButton();
        createPanel();
    }

    private void createButton() {
        reset = new JButton("Restart");
        ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
        reset.addActionListener(listener);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(null);
        component.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);
        reset.setBounds(0, 725, 100, 50);
        p2.add(component);
        p2.add(reset);
        add(p2);
    }

    class ClickListener implements ActionListener {

        public ClickListener(){

        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          reset.setFocusable(false);
          component.resetGame();
        }

    }
}



package riddle;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import java.awt.Color;
import static java.awt.Frame.NORMAL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GameField {

    public String[][] field;
    private String grass, wall, note, end, theRiddle, theAnswer;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayG;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayW;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayN;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayE;
    private Riddle riddle;
    private int instantRight, count, wrongs, retries;
    private boolean ok = false;

    public GameField() {
        field = new String[10][10];
        grass = "Grass";
        wall = "Wall";
        note = "Note";
        end = "End";
        theRiddle = "";
        theAnswer = "";
        instantRight = 0;
        count = 0;
        wrongs = 0;
        retries = 0;
        arrayG = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 9, 10, 19, 20, 29, 30, 39, 40, 49, 50, 59, 60, 69, 70, 79, 80, 89, 90, 99));
        arrayW = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 31, 38, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 51, 58, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 71, 78, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 91, 98));
        arrayN = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(17, 35, 32, 54, 57, 76, 72, 94));
        arrayE = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(97));
        riddle = new Riddle();
        fillField();
    }

    public String checkField(int x, int y) {
        String result = "";
        if (field[y][x] == "Wall") {
            result = wall;
        } else if (field[y][x] == "Note") {
            result = note;
        } else if (field[y][x] == "End") {
            result = end;
            endGame();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void fillField() {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                if (arrayG.contains(k)) {
                    field[i][j] = grass;
                } else if (arrayW.contains(k)) {
                    field[i][j] = wall;
                } else if (arrayN.contains(k)) {
                    field[i][j] = note;
                } else if (arrayE.contains(k)) {
                    field[i][j] = end;
                }

                k++;
            }
        }

    }

    public void setField(int x, int y) {
        field[x][y] = null;
    }

    public boolean riddleTime() {
        boolean check = false;
        theRiddle = riddle.generateRiddle();
        theAnswer = riddle.getAnswer();
        while (!check) {
            check = checkReply(theRiddle, theAnswer);
        }
        return check;
    }

    public boolean checkReply(String question, String answer) {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/bad.png"));
        ImageIcon image2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/good.png"));
        String[] option = {"Yes", "Quit"};
        String reply = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);

        if (reply.contains(answer.toLowerCase()) || reply.contains(StringUtils.capitalize(answer)) || reply.contains(answer.toUpperCase())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, riddle.getResponseC(), "", NORMAL, image2);
            ok = true;
            if (count == 0) {
                instantRight++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        } else {
            wrongs++;
            int selectedValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, riddle.getResponseW(), "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, image, option, NORMAL);
            if (selectedValue == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                checkReply(question, answer);
                retries++;
            }
            if (selectedValue == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            count++;
        }

        return ok;
    }

    private void endGame() {
        ImageIcon bad = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/endingbad.png"));
        ImageIcon good = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/endinggood.png"));
        ImageIcon info = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/info.png"));
        if (instantRight >= 6) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", NORMAL, good);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><center><br><br>Instant Rights: " + instantRight + "\n" + "\n" + "Wrongs: " + wrongs + "\n" + "\n" + "Retries: " + retries + "\n" + "\n" + "          Wisdom Level: " + indicate(instantRight, wrongs, retries), "                      Statistics", NORMAL, info);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", NORMAL, bad);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n" + "Instant Rights: " + instantRight + "\n" + "\n" + "Wrongs: " + wrongs + "\n" + "\n" + "Retries: " + retries + "\n" + "\n" + "           Wisdom Level: " + indicate(instantRight, wrongs, retries), "                      Statistics", NORMAL, info);
        }
    }

    public String indicate(int instantRight, int wrongs, int retries) {
        String level = "";

        if (instantRight >= 6 && wrongs <= 4 && retries <= 4) {
            level = "HIGH";
        } else if (instantRight <= 3 && wrongs > 6 && retries > 6) {
            level = "LOW";
        } else {
            level = "AVERAGE";
        }
        return level;
    }

    public void resetGame(){
        fillField();
        riddle.resetGame();
        instantRight = 0;
        wrongs = 0;
        retries = 0;
        count = 0;    
    }


}
package riddle;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GameDraw extends JComponent {

    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private int RWIDTH;
    private int RHEIGHT;
    private int manX;
    private int manY;
    private BufferedImage man, grass, wall, note, end;
    private Man m;
    private GameField f;

    public GameDraw() {
        //Integer variables
        rows = 9;
        columns = 9;
        RWIDTH = 70;
        RHEIGHT = 70;
        manX = 2;
        manY = 0;
        f = new GameField();
        m = new Man(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        URL resourceMan = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/man.png");
        try {
            man = ImageIO.read(resourceMan);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Er ging iets mis met het laden van de afbeelding van de speler");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        drawField(g);
        drawMan(g);
        drawObjects(g);

    }

    private void drawField(Graphics g) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Color lightgray = new Color(192, 192, 192);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                g.setColor(lightgray);
                g.fillRect(x, y, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT);
                x += RWIDTH;
            }
            g.setColor(lightgray);
            g.fillRect(x, y, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT);
            x = 0;
            y += RHEIGHT;
        }
    }

    private void drawMan(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(man, manX * RWIDTH, manY * RHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, this);
    }

    public void moveMan(int x, int y) {
        manX = x;
        manY = y;
        repaint();
        System.out.println(manX + " " + manY);
    }

    private void drawObjects(Graphics g) {
        URL resourceGrass = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/Grassy.png");
        URL resourceWall = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/wall.png");
        URL resourceNote = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/note.png");
        URL resourceEnd = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/chest.png");

        //Grass object
        try {
            grass = ImageIO.read(resourceGrass);
            wall = ImageIO.read(resourceWall);
            note = ImageIO.read(resourceNote);
            end = ImageIO.read(resourceEnd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Er ging iets mis met het laden van de afbeelding van de speler");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < rows + 1; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < columns + 1; i++) {
                if (f.field[i][j] == "Grass") {
                    g.drawImage(grass, j * RWIDTH, i * RHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, this);
                }
                if (f.field[i][j] == "Wall") {
                    g.drawImage(wall, j * RWIDTH, i * RHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, this);
                }
                if (f.field[i][j] == "Note") {
                    g.drawImage(note, j * RWIDTH, i * RHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, this);
                }
                if (f.field[i][j] == "End") {
                    g.drawImage(end, j * RWIDTH, i * RHEIGHT, RWIDTH, RHEIGHT, this);
                }
}
}
}

    public void repaintField(int x, int y) {
        f.field[x][y] = null;
        repaint();
    }

    public void resetGame(){
        f.resetGame();
        m.resetGame();
        System.out.println(manX + " " + manY);
    }
}

package riddle;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Man implements KeyListener {

    private int locationX;
    private int locationY;
    private GameDraw draw;
    private GameField field;

    public Man(GameDraw draw) {
        locationX = 2;
        locationY = 0;
        this.draw = draw;
        field = new GameField();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        String check;
        boolean pass;
        switch (key) {

            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                locationY--;

                if (locationY < 0) {
                    locationY++;
                }
                check = field.checkField(locationX, locationY);
                if (!"Wall".equals(check) && !"Note".equals(check) && !"End".equals(check)) {
                    draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                } else if (check.equals("Wall") || check.equals("End")) {
                    locationY++;
                } else if (check.equals("Note")) {
                    pass = field.riddleTime();
                    if (pass) {
                        clearNote(locationX, locationY);
                        draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                    } else {
                        locationY++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                locationY++;

                if (locationY > 9) {
                    locationY--;
                }
                check = field.checkField(locationX, locationY);
                if (!"Wall".equals(check) && !"Note".equals(check) && !"End".equals(check)) {
                    draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                }
                if (check.equals("Wall") || check.equals("End")) {
                    locationY--;
                } else if (check.equals("Note")) {
                    pass = field.riddleTime();
                    if (pass) {
                        clearNote(locationX, locationY);
                        draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                    } else {
                        locationY--;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                locationX--;
            ;
                check = field.checkField(locationX, locationY);
                if (!"Wall".equals(check) && !"Note".equals(check) && !"End".equals(check)) {
                    draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                }
                if (check.equals("Wall") || check.equals("End")) {
                    locationX++;
                } else if (check.equals("Note")) {
                    pass = field.riddleTime();
                    if (pass) {
                        clearNote(locationX, locationY);
                        draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                    } else {
                        locationX++;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                System.out.println(locationX + " " + locationY);
                locationX++;

                check = field.checkField(locationX, locationY);
                if (!"Wall".equals(check) && !"Note".equals(check) && !"End".equals(check)) {
                    draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                }
                if (check.equals("Wall") || check.equals("End")) {
                    locationX--;
                } else if (check.equals("Note")) {
                    pass = field.riddleTime();
                    if (pass) {
                        clearNote(locationX, locationY);
                        draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
                    } else {
                        locationX--;
                    }
                }
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void clearNote(int x, int y) {
        field.setField(y, x);
        draw.repaintField(y, x);
    }

    public void resetGame(){
        locationX = 2;
        locationY = 0;
        draw.moveMan(locationX, locationY);
        System.out.println(locationX + " " + locationY);
      }
}

package riddle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Riddle {

    private ArrayList<String> riddles;
    private ArrayList<String> answers;
    private ArrayList<String> correct;
    private ArrayList<String> wrong;
    private ArrayList<Integer> used;
    private ArrayList<Integer> used2;
    private Random ran;
    private int indexAnswer;

    public Riddle() {
        riddles = new ArrayList<String>();
        answers = new ArrayList<String>();
        correct = new ArrayList<String>();
        wrong = new ArrayList<String>();
        used = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        used2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ran = new Random();
        fillRiddles();
        fillAnswers();
        fillCorrect();
        fillWrong();
    }

    private void fillRiddles() {
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Riddle\\src\\resources\\riddles.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.nextLine();
                riddles.add(s);

            }
        }
    }

    private void fillAnswers() {
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Riddle\\src\\resources\\answers.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.nextLine();
                answers.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillCorrect() {
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Riddle\\src\\resources\\correct.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.nextLine();
                correct.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillWrong() {
        Scanner sc2 = null;
        try {
            sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Riddle\\src\\resources\\wrong.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
            while (s2.hasNext()) {
                String s = s2.nextLine();
                wrong.add(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public String generateRiddle() {
        String theRiddle = "";
        int index = ran.nextInt(riddles.size());

        if (!used.contains(index)) {
            theRiddle = riddles.get(index);
            indexAnswer = index;
            used.add(index);
        } else {
            theRiddle = generateRiddle();
        }
        return theRiddle;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        String theAnswer = answers.get(indexAnswer);
        return theAnswer;
    }

    public String getResponseC() {
        String response = "";
        int index = ran.nextInt(correct.size());

        if (!used2.contains(index)) {
            response = correct.get(index);
            used2.add(index);
        } else {
            response = getResponseC();
        }
        return response;
    }

    public String getResponseW() {
        String response = "";
        int index = ran.nextInt(wrong.size());
        response = wrong.get(index);
        return response;
    }

    public void resetGame(){
        riddles.clear();
        answers.clear();
        wrong.clear();
        correct.clear();
        used.clear();
        used2.clear();
        fillRiddles();
        fillAnswers();
        fillCorrect();
        fillWrong();
        indexAnswer = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your Riddle class?

Comment: Welcome to SO. TL; DR . Consider posting [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. I added the riddle class.

Comment: Someone please help me!